How to compile with RAD Studio C++ Builder 12 BCC64 using AVX, SSE, F16C extensions?
I'm just compiling some plain C code under C++ Builder 12 for x64 (the compiler called from the IDE is BCC64.EXE) and when I enable some macros in third party headers related to CPU extensions like AVX, SSE and F16C I get error messages like these:
[bcc64 Error] d2ml.c(483): '__builtin_ia32_vcvtps2ph' needs target feature f16c
[bcc64 Error] d2ml.c(1215): always_inline function '_mm256_loadu_ps' requires target feature 'sse4.2', but would be inlined into function 'quantize_row_q8_0' that is compiled without support for 'sse4.2'
My CPU is a i5-4660 which apparently supports those extensions.
Does C++ Builder 12 x64 support these CPU extensions? If so, how can I compile using them?
I've reviewed the project options within the IDE but can't find anything related to enable these extensions. Also searched the command line options and tried clang "-mf16c", "-msse" and similar options but they don't seem to be supported. I've searched a lot but found nothing and it sounds weird to me that the very latest version of C++ Builder doesn't support those but on the other hand it reports related errors when compiling.
Thanks!
